# globbing pattern to copy files from a particular folder within another folder

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, glob, grunt-contrib-copy

I have the following directories tree:

```
- client
   - plugins
      - plugin1
      - plugin2
      - plugin3
         - widgets
           - widget1
           - widget2
             - resources
               - img
```

I need to copy all files from resources belonging to any particular plugin widget into one folder using grunt copy, so I'm using the following globbing pattern to find those files:

```
src: 'client/plugins/**/*/resources/img/*'
```

But it doesn't seem to be able to find them, so I guess the pattern is wrong. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you please take names of files/directories and explain the problem again?

Comment: sorry, didn't understand what you mean. could you please rephrase the question?

Comment: Same here. I was asking about source and destination. Can you take names from ur example given. Generalized sentences can cause confusion.

Comment: Ok, I need to copy files from `img` folders which are placed inside `plugin1/widget1`, `plugin1/widget2`...`pluginN/widgetN` folders.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use a specific directory after using the `**` pattern because that already matches any subfolder. I think you'll need to be more specific:

```
src: 'client/plugins/*/widgets/*/resources/img/*'
```

If you can't use "widgets" exactly, then you'll need to find another alternative, maybe just using another `/*/`. You can find all of the globbing options in the [node-glob Github repo README file](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer). This includes things like anti-patterns if it comes to that.

Comment: Just checked my path again, I was missing a directory, so this question should be deleted. It works OK the way I composed it `src: 'client/missing-dir/plugins/**/*/resources/img/*'`

Comment: I'm glad that you figured it out! You should vote to delete if you think that's best.